# ld: framework not found AudioUnit,ios9

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, exit-code, juce

I'm trying to compile my iOS project with XCode 7.2.1 on OSX El Capitan. 
I have an XCode project, that uses libVLC. The XCode project was created by JUCE. I have downloaded one "VLC for iOS" nightly build from [here](http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/ios/) and have added MobileVLCKit.framework to the linked Frameworks.

To be complete I've added this frameworks to link (in this order):

- MobileVLCKit.framework
- AudioUnit.framework
- AVFoundation.framework

The XCode linker complains about a missing framework, that was included:

> ld: framework not found AudioUnit
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is my XCode Call:

> Ld build/Debug/Video.app/Video normal i386
>       cd /Users/christoph/Desktop/Video/Builds/iOS
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.2
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk -L/Users/christoph/Desktop/Video/Builds/iOS/build/Debug -F/Users/christoph/Desktop/Video/Builds/iOS/build/Debug -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -F/Users/christoph/Downloads -filelist /Users/christoph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-dmlikbmjwevxfmgmwzysjxijcuhs/Build/Intermediates/Video.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Video.build/Objects-normal/i386/Video.LinkFileList -mios-simulator-version-min=9.2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -framework AudioUnit -framework AVFoundation /Users/christoph/Downloads/MobileVLCKit-binary/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/christoph/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Video-dmlikbmjwevxfmgmwzysjxijcuhs/Build/Intermediates/Video.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Video.build/Objects-normal/i386/Video_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/christoph/Desktop/Video/Builds/iOS/build/Debug/Video.app/Video

---

What I don't understand is.. I added the Framework "AudioUnit.framwork" under "Build Phases" -> "Link Binaries with libraries"

The target is iOS.

Some help would be very nice!

Comment: Try adding CoreAudio or AudioToolbox instead of AudioUnit

Comment: Ok. Now I get 200 more error :-(

Comment: Here they are: http://pastebin.com/1yXN2zgU

Comment: Now it looks like it doesn't know about UIKit. Something is not right with your project. Try adding UIKit framework.

Comment: Aded UIKit -> http://pastebin.com/nYZzAc86. Seems like there is missing some more. Is there a way to add missing frameworks automatically?

Comment: I don't think so, but they should be added by default. You could look at the prefix of the errors and add the rest if it fixes them. For instance CG -> Core Graphics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

- AudioToolbox framework `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`
- CoreAudio framework.  `#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>`

And also remove `AudioUnit.framework` and try

your project requires **CFNetwork**, **SystemConfiguration**, **MobileCoreServices**,**libz.tbd**, **libxml2**, **Core Text**

[image]

```
CT  - > CoreText
CG  - > Core graphics
CM  - > Core Motion
CV  - > Core Video
VT  - > Video ToolBox
VD  - > Acclerate Framework
OBJC_CLASS_$_CAEAGLLayer     - > OpenGL and QuartzCore
```

Comment: Where do I add that? At the Top of main.cpp?

Comment: Ok. Now I get "Reference to 'AudioBuffer' is ambiguous"

Comment: Thanks for the Image :-) I've added these: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4298/4vbqksnx_png.htm But I get various more linker errors. How to let it search automatically?

Comment: @Christoph - I am not seen anything on that url

Comment: @Christoph -- happy to hear, what u modified

Comment: I think I've now learned to add the frameworks that were missing. Only this erros I couldn't fix: http://pastebin.com/Q7rJcsMV

Comment: QuartzCore was missing!! Thanks very much (especially @Anbu.Karthik)! App compiled successfully!

Comment: @Christoph -- welcome bro, your question is good one , please update once, it is useful for future user

Answer (score 1):

Please remove AudioUnit.framwork and clean it and run.